# Column of filtered Dataframe results in empty Series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filter, conditional-statements

I have this code snippet with the goal of filling sublists with values of a dataframe-column, but only with the records that match a certain value in another column.

**The last row is most relevant**, but I added the frame.

```
    for key, value in dict1.items():
    if key[0] + "rel" in dict2:
        i = int(key[0])
        name_col = df1.columns[int(value)]
        lists_dict1[i] = df1.loc[df1["header5"] == 1, name_col].tolist()
```

**My problem is that the sublists lists_dict1[i] are empty in the end.**
It must be the last row(?), because...

Here is some background with things I already tested:

`i = int(key[0])` 
*Printed this separately and it works (e.g. 0 and 2), which also shows, that the If-statement is activated*

`name_col = df1.columns[int(value)]` 
*Printed this and it gives me actual name of the column*

`print(df1["header5"])` 
*Column exists; values as expected (0 or 1)*

`print(df1.loc[df1["header5"] == 1, name_col].tolist())` 
***empty list >> Why?***

`print(df1.loc[df1["header5"] == 1, "crit_abs"])` 
***empty Series object***

**dict1**
    {'0ber': '0', '1ber': '1', '2ber': '2', '3ber': '3'}

**dict2**
    {'0rel': '0', '2rel': '2', '1abs': '1', '3abs': 'ja'}

**df1** (sample; only for context; there is no issue)

```
df1 = {"header1": ["abc1", "abc2", "abc3"], "header2": [1, 1, 0], "header3": ["def5", "def8", "def2"], "header4": ["ja", "nein", "ja"], "header5": [1, 0, 1]}
df1 = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(df1)
```

Comment: What does df1 contain?
If I use:

import pandas as pd
df1Data = [
    {'header5': 1, 'crit_abs': 'one'},
    {'header5': 0, 'crit_abs': 'zero'}
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1Data)
print(df1.loc[df1['header5'] == 1, 'crit_abs'])

I get:
`0    one Name: crit_abs, dtype: object`

(Sorry can't figure out how to format comment)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question and added a the DataFrame (sample) for context!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in how you are structuring the code around the examples you give. The following example strings together the different parts of your code and works. Are you able to get this example to run?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {"header1": ["abc1", "abc2", "abc3"], "header2": [1, 1, 0], "header3": ["def5", "def8", "def2"], "header4": ["ja", "nein", "ja"], "header5": [1, 0, 1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df1)

dict1 = {'0ber': '0', '1ber': '1', '2ber': '2', '3ber': '3'}
dict2 = {'0rel': '0', '2rel': '2', '1abs': '1', '3abs': 'ja'}

lists_dict1 = {}

for key, value in dict1.items():
    print('Key (' + key + ') Value (' + value + ')')
    if key[0] + "rel" in dict2:
        i = int(key[0])
        name_col = df1.columns[int(value)]
        print('Detected Valid Name Col = ' + name_col)
        lists_dict1[i] = df1.loc[df1["header5"] == 1, name_col].tolist()

print('Output Lists Dictionary: ' + str(lists_dict1))
```

When I run this, it returns:

```
Key (0ber) Value (0)
Detected Valid Name Col = header1
Key (1ber) Value (1)
Key (2ber) Value (2)
Detected Valid Name Col = header3
Key (3ber) Value (3)
Output Lists Dictionary: {0: ['abc1', 'abc3'], 2: ['def5', 'def2']}
```

If the example I gave works for you, you likely need to look at how you are structuring the code in your project. It's possible that `df1`, `dict1`, `dict2`, or `lists_dict1` are not being defined properly beforehand, or they are being over-written afterwards.

If the example I gave does not work, what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! I tried your code and it works for me! So, right before the problematic statement (last one in my If-statement), I printed all relevant objects (2 dicts and the DataFrame), which were all correct. Then I changed `lists_dict1[i] = ...` (this is a list of sublists, by the way) to `lists_dict1[i].append(...)`, which helped in the way, that the resulting list is not empty but `[['Series([], Name: header1, dtype: object)'], [], ['Series([], Name: header3, dtype: object)'], []]`. Using `.tolist()` at the end results in an empty list. There must be an issue with the filtering...